# Hide views without leaving gap

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I’m trying toggle visibility between two sections (views) within a scrollview (that gets triggered by a segment control), the thing is I don’t want a gap where the hidden element was.

Currently what I’m doing is in `ViewDidAppear` I’m storing the two views frame and then when I need to toggle the visibility of the views I’m setting the view that I want to hide’s frame to `CGRecZero` and *moving* the other view into the “top” position by setting it’s frame to its initial frame and modifying its origin.y property. The problem is that as soon as I scroll the view’s frames seem to get reset and I’m left with a gap.

Here's an example of my code

```
if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    [self.firstView setHidden:YES];
    [self.firstView setFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.secondView setHidden:NO];
    CGRect frmTmp = secondViewRec;
    frmTmp.origin.y = orgPoint.y;
    [self.secondView setFrame:frmTmp];

} else {
    [self.secondView setHidden:YES];
    self.secondView.frame = CGRectZero;
    [self.firstView setHidden:NO];
    CGRect frmTmp = firstViewRec;
    firstViewRec.origin.y = orgPoint.y;

    self.firstView.frame = frmTmp;
}
```

I’m not set on using a scrollview directly, I have also tried using a Static `UITableView` and hiding the cells but I was again left with gaps in the interface which is I why I’m trying this approach. 
Any suggestions? Is there perhaps an easier way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've solved this is by attaching and removing views from a parent view.  The parent view for me is a scrollview.  Here is some hacked copy paste of my code:

```
#define LIST_BUTTON_INDEX      0
#define LOCATION_BUTTON_INDEX  1
#define ACTIVITIES_DETAIL_MODE_DETAILS   0
#define ACTIVITIES_DETAIL_MODE_MAP       1

-(void)detailsButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self selectButton:LIST_BUTTON_INDEX];   // change the segment control
    [self displayView:ACTIVITIES_DETAIL_MODE_DETAILS];
}
-(void)mapButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self selectButton:LOCATION_BUTTON_INDEX];  // change the segment control
    [self displayView:ACTIVITIES_DETAIL_MODE_MAP];
}


-(void) displayView:(int)displayMode
{
    self.mode = displayMode;

    switch (self.mode)
    {
        case ACTIVITIES_DETAIL_MODE_DETAILS:
        {
            [self clearScrollViewSubviews];

            self.detailsController = [[ActivityDetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityDetailsView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:self.detailsController.view];
            CGRect f = self.detailsController.view.frame;
            f.size.height  -= 20;
            self.scrollView.contentSize = f.size;
        }
        break;

        case ACTIVITIES_DETAIL_MODE_MAP:
        {
            [self clearScrollViewSubviews];
            self.mapController = [[ActivityMap alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActivityDetailsLocationView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:self.mapController.view];
            CGRect f = self.mapController.view.frame;
            f.size.height  -= 20;
            self.scrollView.contentSize = f.size;
        }
        break;
    }

}
-(void)clearScrollViewSubviews
{
    if(self.detailsController != nil)
    {
        [self.detailsController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if(self.mapController != nil)
    {
        [self.mapController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: From your code it looks like you have your views in separate nibs and are attaching them accordingly. I'll give that approach a try and let you know. Thanks for your response.

Comment: This is correct. I didn't realize you were using interface-builder, but now I see the tag :)

Comment: OK I'll need to do some refactoring to try your approach, I need to run now but I'll update after I try it.